# Using jquery ajax to serialize data and submit into mysql database

Tags: php, jquery

The problem i have is that whenever it inserts the data into the database it doesn't redirect the user to the invoice.php page. Please guys i really need your help.

This is the html code:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
<input type="text" name="resident_address" id="resident_address"/>
<input type="text" name="price" id="status"/>
<input type="hidden" name="status" id="status" value="0"/>
</form>
```

This is the jquery code:

```
var dataString = $('#applyform').serialize();
$.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "applyform.php",
                        cache: false,
                        data: dataString,
                        beforeSend: function()
                        {
                            $(".apply_error").hide();
                        },
                        success: function(html) {

                            if (html == "true")
                            {
                                // You can redirect to other page here....
                                window.location.href = 'invoice.php';
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //window.location.href = 'apply.php';
                                $("div.apply_error").html("Wrong details").show();

                            }
                        }                
                    });
```

this is the php which is the applyform.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
   $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (resident_address, price, status) VALUES ('$addressfields', '$price', '$status')");

   if($result){
      echo "true";
   }

}
```

Comment: Maybe you have a mysql error. Are you checking the query is Ok?

Answer (score 1):

you are not posting a `POST` var called "Submit" so your

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
```

will always evaluate to `false` and your mysql query is never executed.